# How to call custom function inside generic class base view

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

How to call the custom function in update function, my views is this-

```
class StokeBulkUpdate(generics.APIView):
 ......
    def custom_function(list):
        return list

    def update(self, request,*args,**kwargs):
        data = self.request.data
        custom_function
```

Answer (score 1):

The custom function is a property of the class, which can be accessed via `self`:

```
class StokeBulkUpdate(generics.APIView):

   def custom_function(self, list):
       return list

   def update(self, request,*args,**kwargs):
       data = self.request.data
       self.custom_function(data)
```

If you don't want to implicitly pass `self` to your method (like in your example), you need to use `@staticmethod`:

```
class StokeBulkUpdate(generics.APIView):

   @staticmethod
   def custom_function(list):
       return list

   def update(self, request,*args,**kwargs):
       data = self.request.data
       self.custom_function(data)
```